# OData Action and Function with same route

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

I've registered a function as follows:

```
individualType.Function(nameof(IndividualsController.Photo)).Returns<byte[]();
```

Function definition is:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns a photo for the specified individual.
/// </summary>
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IHttpActionResult Photo([FromODataUri] int key, [FromUri] string size = "M", [FromUri] string shape = "S")
```

A request has come in for us to be able to upload photos. The desired way to do this would be to post to the same endpoint.

When I registered the action as follows, both endpoints do not work.

```
var action = individualType.Action(nameof(IndividualsController.Photo));
action.Parameter<string>("hexEncodedPhoto");
action.Returns<UploadIndividualPhotoResult>();
```

When I change it to this, both work but at different endpoints which is undesirable.

```
var action = individualType.Action(nameof(IndividualsController.UploadPhoto));
action.Parameter<string>("hexEncodedPhoto");
action.Returns<UploadIndividualPhotoResult>();
```

The signature of this method is currently:

```
[HttpPost]
[Auth(AccessRight = SecurityType.PeopleEdit)]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UploadPhoto([FromODataUri] int key, ODataActionParameters parameters)
```

Is it possible to have both a Function (GET) and an Action (POST) on the same route in OData?

Answer (score 0):

From OData spec perspective, every element under same namespace should have an unique name. So, I don't think your requirement is reasonable.

Please let me know if it's wrong.